# Can a mapping template for api gateway have both dynamic and hard coded values

Tags: aws-api-gateway, vtl

I’m trying to map an API gateway request to a lambda. 
The mapping template I’m using is

```
{
  "method": "$context.httpMethod",
  "body" : $input.json('$'),
  "headers": {
    #foreach($param in $input.params().header.keySet())
    "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end
  },
  "queryParams": {
    #foreach($param in $input.params().querystring.keySet())
    "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().querystring.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end
  },
  "pathParams": {
    #foreach($param in $input.params().path.keySet())
    "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().path.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end
  },
  "source_ip" : "$context.identity.sourceIp"
}
```

The problem is that I would also like to also hard code a query string param that the user doesn’t have to pass in (for user experience reasons) but my lambda is expecting.
I would like to do something like this

```
{
   “queryParams” : 
      “myrequiredkey” : “foo” }
}
```

}

However, when I try combining these two templates, the result is that I am always overwriting all the queryParams and the lambda receives in its event {"queryParams": "foo"}}. But I want to also have any other query params get sent it as well. 
Is there a way I can add in a hard-coded query param and **not** override all the dynamically mapped params?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this :

```
{
  "method": "$context.httpMethod",
  "body" : $input.json('$'),
  "headers": {
    #foreach($param in $input.params().header.keySet())
    "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
  },
  "queryParams": {
    #foreach($param in $input.params().querystring.keySet())
    "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().querystring.get($param))",
    #end
    "myrequiredkey":"foo"
  },
  "pathParams": {
    #foreach($param in $input.params().path.keySet())
    "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().path.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
  },
  "source_ip" : "$context.identity.sourceIp"
}
```

I removed `#if($foreach.hasNext),#end` and directly put you required param in your object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @BTL! I’m going to try this out. Just wondering, what do you think the solution would be if I were to use the request mapping pass through that aws provides? (In their template they dynamically create the objects, including querystring)

Comment: Accepting answer as it does work perfectly and answers my original question accurately

Comment: You're welcome ! 
To answer your comment, I'm not sure. I would be harder...
Well I think your way of doing it is good enough.